# "static const int" causes linking error (undefined-reference)

Tags: c++, gcc, static, constants, stdvector

I am baffled by the linker error when using the following code:

```
// static_const.cpp -- complete code
#include <vector>

struct Elem {
    static const int value = 0;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<Elem> v(1);
    std::vector<Elem>::iterator it;

    it = v.begin();
    return it->value;
}
```

However, this fails when linking -- somehow it needs to have a symbol for the static const "value."

```
$ g++ static_const.cpp 
/tmp/ccZTyfe7.o: In function `main':
static_const.cpp:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `Elem::value'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

BTW, this compiles fine with -O1 or better; but it still fails for more complicated cases.  I am using gcc version 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13).

Any ideas what might be wrong with my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird undefined symbols of static constants inside a struct/class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891067/weird-undefined-symbols-of-static-constants-inside-a-struct-class)

Comment: Thanks for the useful link!  It also shows an alternative solution, `struct Elem { enum { value = 0 }; }`, which seems pretty attractive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ - defining static const integer members in class definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025997/c-defining-static-const-integer-members-in-class-definition)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to initialize it inside the *struct*, you can do it too:

```
struct Elem {
    static const int value = 0;
};

const int Elem::value;
```

Comment: This is cool! It works. It does not make sense to not initialize it in the structure (class) if you can (know the value at that point) because otherwise all the possible optimizations would be lost. (i.e. passing 0 directly instead of loading 0 from some memory address.)

Comment: If this is really const, there is the alternative of the "enum hack", see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891067/weird-undefined-symbols-of-static-constants-inside-a-struct-class The problems are also described there: before c++11 enums have no decent "type" like `int`, so std::min, std::make_pair etc. will not guess their template argument...

Answer (score 5):

Try writing it as

```
struct Elem {
    static const int value;
};

const int Elem::value = 0;

etc
```

.

Comment: This will unfortunately not work, when the value is a label in switch statement.

Comment: @Petr Sorry, not sure what to tell you there.  I haven't used C++ in a few years, so I don't know if that's peculiar to the `static const` or what.

Comment: I should have made myself more clear. I tried to point out to anyone reading you answer, that - although perfectly correct - there are cases when this will not work. For example, if you want to use the `value` as a label in switch, like `switch(x) { case value: break; }`

Answer (score 2):

`static` class members are generally supposed to be defined outside the class (declared inside, defined outside) in one compilation unit.

I don't remember how that interacts with inline initialization of `const` static integral members.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312241/using-a-static-const-int-in-a-struct-class/1312267#1312267

Comment: There's no special rule for the case where the declaration has an initializer---according to the standard, the declared object must be defined somewhere if it is potentially used.  In practice, most compilers are defective in this regard, and will only generate an error for certain uses, not for others, if the definition is missing.  (Which uses are never specified, and usually vary depending on the optimization level.)

Answer (score 2):

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025997/c-defining-static-const-integer-members-in-class-definition): essentially, the problem is that somehow compiler ends up expanding your code into taking the address of Elem::value.

Answer (score 2):

In most of the compilers defining in-class `static const <integral type>` works fine. But some compilers like Android NDK, such in-class definitions results in linker errors. For such case, we may use the typed `enum`s:

```
struct X
{
  enum : int64_t { VALUE = 100; }; // == static const int64_t VALUE = 100;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this?

```
return Elem::value;
```

But the answer is that you are assigning a value in the declaration. This is supposed to work for basic types such as `int`, and is only required for complex types (i.e. classes, such as if you had a string instead of int). What I have found in practice is that this is hit or miss depending on what version of what compiler you are using. And, as you found out, which optimization level.

Comment: That doesn't solve the initialization problem, though.  Also, hit or miss often means undefined behavior.

Comment: Thats just avoiding the question he's asking.

Comment: Actually I did answer it. I said that what he is doing should work (i.e. there is nothing wrong), but in practice does not always work. He appears to have found one of those "does not work" cases.

Comment: No, the "does not work" is the general case. The `value` should really be defined somewhere, not only declared. If you just use the value as a compile time constant, it often "works anyway".