# Undefined reference to static const member when compiled with -O0

Tags: c++

Look at this code:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Foo {
    static const std::map<std::string, int> bar;
};

struct A {
    static const int X = 0;
};

const std::map<std::string, int> Foo::bar = {{"foo", A::X}};

int main() {
}
```

When compiled with `-O0` with either Clang or GCC it gives an undefined reference error:

```
undefined reference to `A::X'
```

(See [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KfY374zTr))

However if you compile with `-O3`, or if you change the `std::string` to `int`, or if you move the definition of `X` outside the class like this

```
struct A {
    static const int X;
};

const int A::X = 1;
```

then it compiles fine!

What's going on here?

Comment: Hmm it may be the same issue as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16957458/265521

Comment: You should use `inline` keyword if you want to initialize static data member inplace

Comment: Are you allowed/able to use C++17 features?

Comment: If yes, you can change it like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/W3eEK7M77).

Comment: Yeah `inline` worked, thanks!